# Swing JPasswordField with inline Mask/Unmask button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, passwords, textfield

So, I've made a class that shows a little eye in a `JPasswordField` and allows masking / unmasking the password.

It looks like this:

[image: Image of passwordfield]

The problem with this is, that while it looks fine using the Windows L&F, it looks absolutely horrible with for example the IntelliJ L&F, since I am simply using the default PasswordField border for the `JPanel` that houses the eye and the actual `JPasswordField`. Now I was wondering, whether there's any way to get such a behaviour by painting the eye directly into the `JPasswordField` and also not ignoring the bounds of the password inside. Meaning that the text inside should never be painted behind the eye, nor should the cursor be able to go behind the eye.

I wanted to avoid writing a completly custom textfield for this, as this sounds like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Component Border](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/).

Comment: You can control the bounds of the text in the JPasswordField with [setMargin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29).

Comment: I'll give both of these a try tomorrow, thanks ;)

Comment: setMargin seems to have no effect whatsoever @VGR

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `SpringLayout` into a `JLayeredPane` like so:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final AbstractButton show = new JCheckBox("Show");

        //Just hide every decorating colors:
        show.setBorderPainted(false);
        show.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        show.setFocusPainted(false);

        final JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(20);
        pass.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, pass.getFont().getSize()));

        final char echo = pass.getEchoChar();
        show.addActionListener(e -> {
            pass.setEchoChar(show.isSelected()? 0: echo);
            pass.requestFocusInWindow();
        });

        //Put the fields in a JLayeredPane:
        final JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();            
        pane.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
        pane.add(pass, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        pane.add(show, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER); //Layer over the DEFAULT_LAYER one.

        //Setup the layout of the pane:
        final SpringLayout layout = (SpringLayout) pane.getLayout();
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pass, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, pane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pass, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, pane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pass, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, pane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pass, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, show, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, pane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, show, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, pane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, show, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pane);

        //Set the preferred size of the pane (it's not automatic with SpringLayout):
        final Dimension showPrefSz = show.getPreferredSize(),
                        passPrefSz = pass.getPreferredSize();
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(showPrefSz.width + passPrefSz.width, Math.max(showPrefSz.height, passPrefSz.height)));

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Unmaskable password field");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Any `Component` will work, so you can put a `JButton` with an *eye* icon instead of a `JCheckBox` which I use.

I am assuming that you are going to `setBorderPainted(false)`, `setContentAreaFilled(false)` and `setFocusPainted(false)` on the button, if at all needed.

Be aware that according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled-boolean-) you shall not call `setOpaque(false)` on an `AbstractButton` and instead use `setContentAreaFilled(false)`.

Here are the relevant Java tutorials:

1. [How to Use SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html).
2. [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

The `SpringLayout.putConstraint` commands which I use in the MRE, are telling the `LayoutManager` first to fill the entire `JLayeredPane` with the `JTextComponent` (4 first commands) and second to stick the `JCheckBox` at the east side of the `JLayeredPane` and also fill the entire height of the `JLayeredPane` with the `JCheckBox`, which makes the text and check box of the `JCheckBox` component to be centered vertically (3 last commands).

Note: you need to set the preferred size of the `JLayeredPane` because the `SpringLayout` is not going to tell it the preferred size according to the components (such as other `LayoutManager`s do).

Comment: Sadly this approach has the exact problem I am trying to avoid, which is that the password renders behind the component on the right in case the password is long or the component is small

Comment: Ok. So what would you want to happen when the text reaches the button?

Comment: It'll just draw behind it

Answer (score 0):

Since VGR recommended me to use `setMargin`, which didn't have an affect, I found out that I could simply achieve the same behaviour by using a compound border that uses the original `JPasswordField` border as the outer border and an `EmtpyBorder` as its inner border in order to make space for the show/hide button. This way the bounds are correct and i can easily write code that changes the tooltip, cursor and whatnot when interacting with the show/hide icon. The icon is then simply drawn in the `paint` method of the `JPasswordField`.

**UPDATE**

So apparently, this approach was also not playing well with the L&F in question and I found that a safer approach was to just override `getInsets()`, since there's no setter method for it.

Yet another solution might have been a `JLayeredPane`.